# get values between nested curly braces with regex php

Tags: php, regex

I have template codes with nested curly braces like this:

```
{code{attributes}}
```

I want both values: '`code`' and '`attributes`', how do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$a = '{code{attributes}}';
$matches = array();

preg_match('/\{(.+)\{(.+)\}\}/', $a, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "{code{attributes}}"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "code"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "attributes"
}
```

Edit: if the attributes are optional, try the following:

```
$a = '{code{attributes}}';
$b = '{code}';

$regex = '/\{(.+?)(?:\{(.+)\})?\}/';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($regex, $a, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

$matches = array();
preg_match_all($regex, $b, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "{code{attributes}}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "code"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "attributes"
  }
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "{code}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "code"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! is there a way to output if there's only one value? `{code}`

Comment: Yes, see my edit. The regex becomes more complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit too general, but perhaps (\{.*?\}) could work?

Tested via [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/index.php3?s=%7Bcode%7Battribures%7D%7D&)